# Export Zabbix Dashboards

Tags: dashboard, zabbix

I got to know recently that we cannot export/import dashboards from Zabbix. Is there any work around for this? I want to export my Development environment zabbix dashboards to Test environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the [dashboard API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api/reference/dashboard).

Use the `.get` calls retrieve the dashboards objects from your Dev environment, then call `.create` on the Test environment.

Watch out for mismatching userids (and/or other ids), if Dev and Test aren't 100% matching!